# Is exitEveryRule the best place to capture rule data (source Line) in Antlr4?

Tags: java, antlr4

I'm trying to grab some data about the source code file and the node. If I want to capture source line number (`int line = ctx.getStart().getLine();`) if it goes in `exitEveryRule` am I correct in thinking that this will execute each time a rule ends? I saw another post that seemed to indicate this was more for errors.

I started to add code to each of the rules but in Java, that's a lot of rules. Seems like I should simply use this and be done. But before I delete and retry, any issues with that approach?

Comment: If you want to apply a function after visiting every node and this fits your use case, then yes. What issues are you anticipating? I'd just go ahead and code it up.

Comment: It does, but I do get surprised once in a while with Antlr and walk into corners I didnt know existed. Most of the examples show modifications to individual rules and looking at those, they seemed more appropriate for exitEvery. So when you DON'T see something you expect, its a good idea to ask. Thank you for responding  !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did in fact work but there were some interesting dependencies on the grammar. It worked as a first effort, but we found we needed to extend the grammar is a few minor ways to get a consistent output. Most were "intermediate" steps so we could create a consistent. So it does work, and it does what you would expect but in the end, we needed to extend it a bit anyway.